# Can one place Lambdas or Func's in String Interpolation statements

Tags: c#, lambda, func, string-interpolation

Consider the following;

```
    public override string ToString()
    {

        return $"{HouseName}{StreetLine1 + " : "}{StreetLine2}{PostalTown + " : "}:{PostCode + " : "}{Country}";
    }
```

This is nothing more than a simple override of ToString() to give end users in an application a little more meaningful information about an address entity than they would otherwise get were no override provided.

HouseName, StreetLine2 and Country are all allowed null values on the backend database. I am wondering if rather than writing separate methods to determine the value of these and then return either nothing or the value + " : " there is a way to do this via a Lambda or func within the actual string interpolation statement itself.

I am still learning my way around C# and what searching I have done to date seems to indicate that this probably isn't possible even with the magical Elvis operator.  However it's equally possible that I've simply misunderstood what I have been reading.

**EDIT**

Following @Evk's answer I created the following quick console app.

```
    namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var adr = new Address { StreetLine1 = "1 Any Road", PostalTown = "Any Town", PostCode = "AB12 3CD" };
            Console.WriteLine($"{(adr.HouseName != null ? " : " + adr.HouseName : "")} : {adr.StreetLine1 } : { (adr.StreetLine2 != null ? " : " + adr.StreetLine2 : "")} : {adr.PostalTown} : {adr.PostCode} ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string HouseName { get; set; }


        public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }

        public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }

        public string PostalTown { get; set; }


        public string PostCode { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This produced the following result

```
 : 1 Any Road :  : Any Town : AB12 3CD
```

In reality I was after

```
 1 Any Road : Any Town : AB12 3CD
```

and as you can see I have not even factored in Country , which had it been set should have produced;

```
 1 Any Road : Any Town : AB12 3CD : Any Country
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly I would just write ``$"{HouseName ?? "nullReplacementString"}"``

Comment: FYI this works ``var test = $"{(Func<string>)(() => "Hello World")}";``

Comment: @RandRandom - Works? It produces `"System.Func'1[System.String]"`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Works as in it compiles :) You are absolutly correct it fails miserably, sorry. How about that beauty: ``var t = $"{((Expression<Func<string>>)(() => "Hello World")).Compile().Invoke()}";`` :D

Comment: @RandRandom if you do it like this: `var test = $"{((Func<string>)(() => "Hello World")).Invoke()}";` it will "work" (that is - result in "Hello World" string).

Comment: @Evk didnt know you could invoke a func, thx for sharing.

Comment: @RandRandom well in your comment above you are doing just that, because `Compile()` returns `Func<string>` on which you then do `Invoke()` :)

Comment: @Evk Facepalm. Never really bothered what the return value of compile was, just knew that this is the way to do it.

Comment: @RandRandom - Careful with compiling expressions - they create an in-memory assembly that never gets garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if rather than writing separate methods to determine the value of
>   these and then return either nothing or the value + " : " there is a
>   way to do this within the actual string interpolation statement itself

You can use "?:" operator, just enclose it in "()":

```
$"{StreetLine1 + (StreetLine2 != null ? " : " + StreetLine2 : "")}";
```

However if you just need to join bunch of strings together - use `String.Join`:

```
String.Join(" : ", new[] {HouseName, StreetLine1, StreetLine2}.Where(c => c != null));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can see that it is quite obviously correct and have marked it accordingly.  My comprehension is clearly not quite up to your level though.  I've edited my question showing what I have got to date and what I would have expected.  Would you be kind enough to explain what I have obviously misunderstood (in terms  of what you're doing) so that I can learn something new from this.  Thanks.

Comment: @DomSinclair well it's too long for comment, so here is "correct" string for your case `$"{(adr.HouseName != null ? adr.HouseName + ":" : "")}{adr.StreetLine1 }{(adr.StreetLine2 != null ? " : " + adr.StreetLine2 : "")} : {adr.PostalTown} : {adr.PostCode} "`. Hope you can see from it what you did wrong. But really - just use `String.Join` to not drive yourself insane, because this approach with so many strings each of which can be either nullable or not is very error prone.

Comment: Thank you for the sound advice, a wise comment indeed!